# Executing Tasks at regular intervals using while(true)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I need to constantly poll a data store for possible updates.  I am achieving this using the following code.  This is a windows forms application by the way.

```
var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

var updateTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            someData = dataStore.GetData();
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            someGrid.DataSource = someData;
        }, uiContext);
    }
});
```

`someData` is a private class field and `someGrid` is a datagrid control.

This seems to work perfectly, but I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving it.  Also, should my outer Task be LongRunning?

**EDIT:**

Ok, at the suggestion of Jon and Henk, I am using a Timer instead:

```
uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

updateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
updateTimer.Elapsed += updateTimer_Elapsed;
updateTimer.Enabled = true;
```

The elapsed event:

```
void updateTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    someData = dataStore.GetData();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        someGrid.DataSource = someData;
    }, uiContext);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use a `Timer` of some kind?

Comment: There is no need to use `Task.StartNew` inside of the timer elapsed event; you're already in a background thread.  Just do your long running operation normally and then either use `StartNew` in the UI context or `control.Invoke` to get back to the UI thread.

Comment: Oh, that makes complete sense - updated post.  Thanks.

Comment: The other 'better way of achieving it' is to have the dataStore signal upon updates.

Comment: On the 'server push' vs 'client pull' front, if the data store is SQL Server, you can use [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I would use a WinForms.Timer (ticks on main thread) and StartNew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Sleep()`ing in a PoolThread you could/should use a Timer.
For WinForms you can simply use the Widows.Forms.Timer.

If you do want to do it this way then Yes, use the Longrunning option. But it is still wasting a Thread.